# add slide up slide down effect level to bootstrap 4 multi dropdown

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I want  slideup, slidedown effect for inner sub-menu also. Now effect is working for first level dropdown on click function only in bootstrap 4.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous">
     
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown link
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: .1rem;
    margin-right: .1rem;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    /*
    if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
        $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
    }
    */
    var $subMenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');

    $subMenu.toggleClass('show');

    $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
        $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass('show');
    });
    return false;
});

$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(300);
});

$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
});
```

Comment: Don't link to external sites unless it's an actual codepen that replicated the problem you're facing. You can include the code in your question just fine. Having to go off-site to analyze the problem is exceptionally tedious, not to mention that the links might die / change over time, removing a lot from the question in the future for people who come across the same problems.. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: how can i edit my post?

Comment: you click the edit button underneath your post, but no worries @Kafia Kahn. I (and/or others) took the liberty to do it for you. Just gotta await the peer review for the changes to follow through.